# How to derive my own DataGridColumnHeaderStyle from the default DataGridColumnHeader?

Tags: wpf, styles, wpfdatagrid

I've made a stlye for DataGridColumnHeader, and I want to derive that from the default DataGridColumnHeader, so I do this:

```
  <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}" x:Key="ColumnHeaderStyle" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                <Grid VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" >
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0"  Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                    </TextBlock>
                  ......
               </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

but it's not work, it seems the DataGrid doesn't have the `defaultStyle` anymore, I think the problem is setting template for DataGridColumnHeader in the code above, but what should I do?

Comment: What properties are not getting inherited?

Comment: For example I can't change the width of the columns by using the mouse left button click between 2 column headers anymore!

Comment: @raha You can inherit styles using `BasedOn`, but you can't "inherit" individual style properties ... and overriding the `ControlTemplate` property is going to remove a lot of the default functionality.  I'd suggest asking what exactly you're trying to do.

Comment: @dbaseman :Well,I want to add a TextBox and a Button to  the DataGridColumnHeader,And inherit styles and individual style properties from  the default DataGridColumnHeaderStyle,how can i do that without ControlTemplate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well,I just needed to set ContentTemplate insted of Template!!

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}" x:Key="ColumnHeaderStyle" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}}">
<Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
    <Setter.Value>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" >
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0"  Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                </TextBlock>
              ......
           </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```